# trailing char end of line still gives 0920 at the end of first line

Tags: c

Task is to delete spaces and tabs from the end of input line maintaining line count. Can't use string library. I've done all I could have and still in output file there is 0920 at the end of the first line (using octal dump od -x trim.out) any ideas what else might be wrong with it???

```
#define LINELIM 1000

int getLine(char s[], int lim);

int main (void){
    int  len, i;
    char line1[100];

    while ((len = getLine(line1, LINELIM)) >0){
            for (i=len-2; i>=0; i--){
            if (line1[i] == ' ' || line1[i] == '\t' || line1[i] == '\n'){
                   // professor says it is always true for some reason
                line1[i] = '\0';
            }
            else break;
        }

    if(line1[0]) // not a blank
        printf(" %s\n", line1);
    }

return 0;
}
/*getline: read a line into s, return length*/
int getLine(char s[], int lim){
    int c,i;
    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!= EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i]=c;
    if (c == '\n'){
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Comment: what is this? with `line1[100]`, you're passing `#define LINELIM 1000`???\

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger, because then you can step through the code, line by line, and see what happens, and also check values of variables and results of expressions.

Comment: I want to suggest you try a different approach: First - Read the whole line in one step with `scanf` and apply your replacement logic afterwards. Second - Rewrite your code, it looks horrible and not really maintainable(I guarantee you: In two days you won't understand your good again). Third - There is a huge error in your code where you might write out of bounds of your array - see third line in your getLine function. So rethinking the problem/approach would be preferable here.

Comment: @ckruczek The `scanf` function is not the best solution for reading a *line*, a better function would be `fgets` in that case.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: And your cons against `scanf` are which?

Comment: @ckruczek Which format code do you want to use? `"%s"` which stops scanning on space? `"%["` which is hard to use even for intermediate programmers? Why not use a function that *made* for reading lines?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Well this point goes to you :)

Comment: By the way, [I can't replicate your problem](http://ideone.com/Lc6e5x). The only modifications I made was lowering the limit, adding the `#include <stdio.h>` and printing the string inside single quotation characters. The `stdin` input contain trailing spaces and tabs and a newline.

Answer (score 1):

At first you have to include header `<stdio.h>`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

If you call the function with the second parameter equal to `LINELIM`

```
getLine(line1, LINELIM)
```

then `line1` has to be defined with the same size

```
char line1[LINELIM];
```

As for me I would rewrite function `getline` the following way:)

```
int getLine( char s[], int lim )
{
    int c;

    int i = 0;

    while ( i < lim - 1 && ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && ( s[i++] = c ) !='\n' ); 

    s[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}
```

The main loop in main can be written like

```
while ( ( len = getLine( line1, LINELIM ) ) > 0 )
{
    int i = len;

    while ( i != 0 && ( line1[i-1] == ' ' || line1[i-1] == '\t' || line1[i-1] == '\n' ) ) --i;

    line1[i] = '\0';

    if ( line1[0] ) printf( "%s\n", line1 );
}
```

You should move the declaration of `i` from main inside the while loop because except this while loop the variable is not used anywhere in main.

As for your code then setting `i` to `len - 2` is incorrect.

```
for (i=len-2; i>=0; i--){
     ^^^^^^
```

Let's assume that the `line1` contains only the new line character `'\n'`. In this case `len` is equal to `1` and as result i will be equal to `-1`. So the trailing new line character will not be removed.

Comment: Thank for taking the time o explain, I really appreciate it. 
1. getline function is part of the assignment (cannot be changed)
2.  I tried to declare int i inside for and gcc complains ans says that by the new standard declaration only out side;-/
3. in regards of len -2 logic I thought that line terminator \o counts too? if it doesn't than yes my line is wrong.

Comment: @Oleksandr Pimenov  Function getline does not count the terminating zero. As for declaring variable i in the loop then it is shown in my post. Neither compiler will issue an error.